# +/-5V to 0...5V and not failing for +/-12V

Tags: operational-amplifier

I'm trying to convert a voltage that is between -5V and +5V to the range of 0...5V. These voltages can be found in "euroracks"/"doepfer a100"-systems which are modular synthesizers for music.

This conversion is possible with the schematics found at https://masteringelectronicsdesign.com/design-a-bipolar-to-unipolar-converter/

With a TL074 opamp this works fine on my breadboard.

Now there is a problem with that: the input-voltage for my use-case (eurorack/a100 modules) *can* be -12...12V in some cases. In that case (e.g. anything that is outside -5...5V) I would like to clamp it to -5...5V.
Limitting to +5 I can do with a LM336Z-5.0 I think but how can I protect against voltages lower than -5V? (or less than 0V after conversion)

The signal I'm converting is a voltage that represents a frequency. E.g. 3.250V is note C4 [see wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CV/gate#CV)

The output will be send to an arduino adc pin.

Comment: Wow, I knew that the TL074 was still sold, but it's really an "original opamp" as in: it was among the very first FET-based Opamps ever produced; datasheets date back to 1978. I'd strongly recommend using a different opamp, as this needs quite a bit of headroom in terms of supply voltage, has a bit of problem with unity gain and so on.

Comment: @MarcusMüller ah! ok. Maybe an LM358? (asking specifically for that as I have it lying around)

Comment: ha! that's probably even older, but doesn't need as much voltage headroom.

Comment: What current ?? or load R?

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 it is for audio so millivolts I think. i'll add that tot the question itself, i get the feeling that that may be important

Comment: @FolkertvanHeusden that's a voltage, not a current ;) But the audio hint is valueable! what's your signal source, i.e. how "strong" can it be (you'd want to protect the inputs, but that protection needs to withstand the abuse of the source).

Comment: If you "just" need to deal with audio, why not simply use a capacitor to AC couple your signal, e.g. to a gain=1/2 non-inverting opamp amplifier?

Comment: TL 074 =  Supply voltage –0.3 to  36 so no problem with using   Schottky diodes to both rails +5V and 0V then inject 5V offset and gain =1/2

Comment: @MarcusMüller oh haha indeed, that was an elaborate typo :-)
regarding the ac coupling: I don't know if that will work. the signal (an "control voltage" as it is called) is not neccessarily a wave; it can sit at -1V for infinite time in theory. the voltage "selects" a frequency to play.

Comment: ah, so it's not audio then?

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 I thought of a diode, but don't even schottky diodes give a voltage-drop? it is rather important that I know exactly what the voltage was, as it is 1-on-1 related to a frequency to play

Comment: @MarcusMüller maybe not in the sense of the waveforms coming out of a soundcard, no. I'm a software developer by day so my lingo may be off

Comment: @FolkertvanHeusden the diode isn't in series with the signal: It's just one each in "normally blocking" direction to ground and to supply voltage: in case of overvoltage, that diode would conduct.

Comment: @FolkertvanHeusden so, audio signals are signals in the audible range of frequencies, your's is not :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXgq0Z.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

No Amp required. This attenuates to Vin/2 with a 5.0V offset to centre the output to V+/2

Anything  |Vin| >5.2V **clips** with low current from 10k//10k effective  series resistance.

Otherwise if |Vin| < 5V diode is high impedance (off).

If input impedance is 1M then the actual signal is attenuated 5k/1M*100%=0.5% which is less than 1% tolerance of R1,R2

Comment: The point where the box is with '5.0V' means that I have to insert 5V at that point?  Same question for the Vin/2-box.

Comment: If your inputs only accept 0 to 5V input then you need a 5V reference or supply .  Vin/2 is just a test point where you see Vin= +/-5 reduced to 2.5 +/-2.5V and anything larger is clipped. Is that what you need?

Comment: Hi, I've simulated it in circuitjs (http://tinyurl.com/y4woc4en ) and it looks like its output ranges from -0.4 to +5.4. I don't think the arduino adc will like that :-) Is it possible to adjust the minium and maximum voltages?

Comment: @FolkertvanHeusden  That's why CMOS uses special Schottky diode pairs to each rail with 10K in between on inputs. Their low current rating of 5mA makes them small and faster than the CMOS and fast  enough for ESD.  You only have 2 Schottky builtin options in that simulator

Answer (score 1):

A low output impedence version...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3xTXc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The LMC6482AIN is a dual rail to rail input and output op amp.

Comment: Hi James. Am I right that without the buffering the schematic is http://tinyurl.com/y6bpkryn ? In that case: it is clipping the voltage, not shifting and reducing.

Answer (score 0):

I've been spending some time with circuitjs and I think this is what I want:

[schematic in circuitjs](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%2010.20027730826997%2050%205%2043%0Aa%20304%20192%20416%20192%208%205%200%201000000%201.6666234216083613%201.6666666666666665%20100000%0Ar%20304%20112%20416%20112%200%2010000%0Ar%20208%20208%20304%20208%200%2020000%0Ar%20304%20208%20304%20304%200%2010000%0Aw%20304%20112%20304%20176%200%0Aw%20416%20112%20416%20192%200%0Ar%20304%20176%20208%20176%200%2020000%0AR%20208%20208%20144%20208%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0AR%20208%20176%20176%20160%200%201%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0A368%20416%20192%20480%20160%200%200%0Ag%20304%20304%20304%20320%200%0Ao%209%2064%200%204099%2020%206.4%200%204%209%203%208%200%208%203%0A)

[image: schematic picture]

Any voltage between -5V and +5V is scaled and shifted to 0...5V. Furthermore anything outside that range is clipped.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good solution but I have to give most of the credit to Spehro Pefhany who posted a similar circuit on a different thread.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1DzLe.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The TL431 is configured to give a 2.5V reference by tying its REF pinto its Cathode pin.